# media format over SIP?

Tags: sip, rtp

I'm a newbie and a need your help. I have a SIP header like below and it's strange with me @@ please tell me which media this is, and its properties. Thks you.
(sorry because I'm not good at English :( )

```
b=AS:512
t=0 0
m=audio 49198 RTP/AVP 115 102 9 15 0 8 s18 106 99 101
a=rtpmap:115 G7221/32000
a=fmtp:115 bitratg=48000
a=rtpmap:102 G7221/16000
a=fmtp:102 bitrate=32000
a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000
a=rtpmap:15 G728/8000
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:18 G729/8000
a=fmtp:18 annexb=no
a=rtpmap:106 SIREN22/48000
a=fmtp:106 bitrate=64000
a=rtpmap:99 SIREN14/16000
a=fmtp:99 bitrate=48000
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
a=fmtp:101 0-15
a=sendrecv
m=video 49200 RTP/AVP 109 110 111 96 34 31
b=TIAS:512000
a=content:main
a=label:1
a=rtpmap:109 H264/90000
a=fmtp:10= profile-level-id=42801f; max-mbps=108000; max-fs=3600; sar=13
a=rtpmap:110 H264/90000
a=fmtp:110 profile-level-id=42801f; packetization-mode=1; max-mbps=108000; max-fs=3600; sar=13
a=rtpmap:111 H264/90000
a=fmtp:111 profile-level-id=64001f; packetization-mode=1; max-mbps=108000; max-fs=3600; sar=13
a=rtpmap:96 H263-1998/90000
a=fmtp:96 CIF=1;QCIF=1;SQCIF=1;J;T
a=rtpmap:34 H263/90000
a=fmtp:34 CIF=1;QCIF=1;SQCIF=1
a=rtpmap:31 H261/90000
a=fmtp:31 CIF=1;QCIF=1
a=sendrecv
VideoMode:9
```

Comment: What is strange about it?

Answer (score 2):

Just have a look at https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4566 - it describes every field. Start with the `m=...` lines which define the list of codecs available. Then check the `a=...` for each of them to find out what codec it is (`a=rtpmap:`) and what parameters it uses (`a=fmp:`).

Comment: @viraptor Can you please explain the `a=rtpmap` and `a=fmtp`. what are their significance in SDP packet.?

Comment: @rkm_Hodor it's all in the document: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4566#section-8.2.3

Answer (score 0):

The SDP's malformed, because

```
m=audio 49198 RTP/AVP 115 102 9 15 0 8 s18 106 99 101
                                       ^^^ - this isn't a number
```

While the formats in an `m=` line are defined as just tokens, because this uses the `RTP/AVP` profile, these [MUST be payload type numbers](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4566#section-8.2.3).

Comment: Just remove the s and it lines up nicely with the "a" definitions.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by that.